# $f: G→G$ defined by $f(x) =x^2$ is a homomorphism if and only if $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The function $f: G→G$ defined by $f(x) =x^2$ is a homomorphism if and only if $G$ is abelian. 
Can anyone give me any tips how to work on this question?

Comment: What have you tried? There is not really any trick involved here, just the definitions.

Comment: oh i see! just accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Megan, you still don't accept the Peter's answer (and any answer of your other questions) If you don't know how accept an answer you sould see http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** When is it true that $(ax)^2=a^2x^2$? That is $$axax=aaxx$$

**Further hint** Multiplying on the left by $a^{-1}$ and right by $x^{-1}$ gives what?

Comment: oh i see! like homomorphism theory:f(ab)=f(a)f(b), when f(x)=x^2. f(a)=a^2, f(b)=b^2,f(ab)=(ab)^2=a^2b^2. f(ab)=f(a)f(b)! right?

Comment: @Megan Bingo!!! It follows, provided the group is abelian!